# Implement crypt() in php

Tags: php, mysql, crypt

I am trying to encrypt the given password to match one that is in a database. However using `crypt()` gives me a different result each time so it never matches. How can i make this work.

here is the statement that hashes the password given by the user.

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = crypt($_POST['password']);
```

prior to this i manually made a user that had the `crypt('password')` but if I enter 'password' into the field it doesn not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  // get the hashed password from database
  $hashed_password = get_from_db($username);

  if (crypt($password, $hashed_password) == $hashed_password) {
    echo "Password verified!";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
//$pass_entered_from_login is the user entered password
//$crypted_pass is the encrypted password from the
//database or file
if(crypt($pass_entered_from_login,$crypted_pass)) == $crypted_pass)
{
   echo("Welcome to my web site.")
}
```

[**Read more**](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Using-the-PHP-Crypt-Function/)

Answer (score -2):

crypt auto generates the salt each time you use it ............ 
so use the same salt for the user 
do this while registering the user to your database and while checking tooo.

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = crypt($_POST['password'],$_POST['username']);
 }
```

**NOTE: the 2nd parameter is the salt in crypt function**  .

hope it helps :)